# Flask-WTF with Flask-security

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms, flask-security

```
@user.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def create():
    form = CreateUserForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user_datastore.create_user(form)
```

Using both libraries together, is there some way that I can do as in the code above. I want to pass the form (with its fields) directly to create_user, so that I don't have to split each field just to add them there. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried something like the above?

Comment: no, does it work that way?

Comment: I have tried it now, did not work.

Comment: `create_user` accepts keyword arguments that get passed to the user model. If you don't want to do that, you'll have to implement your own version of `create_user`.

Comment: I didn't get your meaning exactly. Please clarify your question more.

Answer (score 0):

Create a user from the form's data and then `put` it in the datastore

```
form = CreateUserForm(request.form)
if form.validate_on_submit():
    user = User()
    form.populate_obj(user) # Copies matching attributes from form onto user
    user_datastore.put(user)
```